# Flutter Custom Title Dropdown (Material Page Filter)

Tags: material-design, flutter

Following the concept of the app bar "page filter" I'd like to put a `DropdownButton` as the title of the `AppBar`. I tried, but it doesn't look good.

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _value = 'one';

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new DropdownButton<String>(
          value: _value,
          items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
            new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text('one'),
              value: 'one',
            ),
            new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text('two'),
              value: 'two'
            ),
          ], 
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() => _value = value);
          },)
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'hello world',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However it looks like: 
[image: ios simulator]

which doesn't follow the material pattern found at the link stated above due to the weird looking underline... bonus: the text and button should be white.

Comment: > which doesn't follow the material pattern found at the link stated above

there's no link

Comment: And I doupt material has any rules about DropDown inside appbar ; as according to material, only string and icons should be used inside appbar.

Comment: @Darky see edit above (link is also here: https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

Comment: On IOS according to the specs the title is centered

Comment: @Darky that's very much unhelpful. I specifically said, "ignoring the left right position because it's being rendered in iOS"

Comment: That's unclear. What is "left right position" ? According to your code, what is rendered is normal.

Comment: @Darky I appreciate you taking the time to read my question, but I would appreciate a little leniency here. If you look at the link you'll see an app bar per the material design specs. It says "All" with a down arrow. On iOS it will be centered. On Android it will be positioned to the left. I was just trying to have people ignore the fact that it was centered in my screenshot as I don't care about that aspect of it.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand the problem. Your question only say "it doesn't looks good" and "ignore left right posistion". If the alignement is not the problem, then what is it ?

Comment: @Darky the underline and the color was my main concern... I'm fairly new to flutter and it's not obvious to me how to manipulate these things or the best practices... See my update; I found how to do some of it, but then another issue occurs - the background of my dropdown becomes black to match the dark theme.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I'll give you a proper answer is a second

Comment: @Darky much appreciated... honestly I can live with what I have now... but understanding the "proper" solution would be great... fyi the only way I figured this out was looking at the implementation of DropdownButton and seeing that the buttons color was dependent on the Brightness (Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? Colors.grey.shade700 : Colors.white70)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButton(
          value: _selectedItem,
          items: _dropdownMenuItems,
          underline: SizedBox(height: 0,),
          //underline: SizedBox(),
          onChanged: onChangeDropdownItem,
        ),
       ],
      ),
    ),
```

Then change your dropdown menu's style here:

```
/// Initialize dropdown menu
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> buildDropdownMenuItems(List menu) {
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = List();
for (String li in menu) {
  items.add(
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: li,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 100, 
        child: Text(li, style:  TextStyle(color: labelColor, fontWeight: 
               FontWeight.bold), 
               textAlign: TextAlign.center, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),),
    ),
  );
}
return items;
```

}

Answer (score 13):

I did find some things that helped my situation... The widgets `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` and `Theme` will help control how the dropdown looks in the title of the `AppBar`

```
new AppBar(
  title: new Theme(
      child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: new DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _value,
        items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
          new DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Text('My Page'),
            value: 'one',
          ),
        ], 
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() => _value = value);
        },
      ),
    ), 
    data: new ThemeData.dark(),
  ),
),
```

However, now the popup's background color is black to match the dark theme... not sure if there's a way to have the theme not affect the actual popup.

I personally can live with the black background color of the popup... unless someone can also solve that.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please just change your code to the one I have mentioned below and this one might work for your app.[image], sorry for the bad editing of the picture.  I have included the full code for your reference,.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _value = 'one';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title:
          new Row(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new DropdownButton<String>(
            value: _value,
            items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
              new DropdownMenuItem(
                child: new Text('one'),
                value: 'one',
              ),
              new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text('two'), value: 'two'),
            ],
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() => _value = value);
            },
          ),

        ],
      )
 ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'hello world',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

See the demo here: https://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/LYpZRqG

Comment: but now the text is an ugly gray... I want it to be white with a white button. The only way that I could accomplish this was by making sure the brigthness was set to dark (and the easiest way to do that was wrap it all in a theme with `new ThemeData.dark()`... this does not solve the question (imo)

Comment: I added a Codepen demo to your answer: https://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/LYpZRqG

Answer (score 0):

To have a white menu, change `data: new Theme.dark()` to `Theme.of(context).copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark))`

But then another problems pop : The menu is white ; but the menu options are written in white too, making them unreadable.

After a deep inspection, it seems like it's currently not possible to have options using a different font color in the iddle state and when the dropdown is focused.
Consider creating an issue on their [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)